# Preserve border-radius while using transform: scale

Tags: android, css, cordova

I would like to know how to preserve border-radius property while using `transform: scale`.

I am using `-webkit-transform: scale(1);` on a pseudo-element `.my-div::after`. `.my-div::after` also has a css rule `border-radius: 50%`. The idea is when I click it, its magnitude scale from 0 to 1.

Everything works perfectly fine in Chrome on desktop, but when I run it on Android webview (this is a Cordova project. I am running it on Android 4.4), the following happens:

1. Border radius is removed
2. `.my-div` scales from 0 to 1 as a rectangle
3. Border radius is restored to the correct value `50%`.

Someone suggested to apply border-radius to the parent, but I cannot apply the border radius to the parent element because I am dealing with a pseudo-element, and applying it to the parent will not produce the expected outcome.

Any suggestions?

**Edit**

Here is what my code looks like in short:

```
.btn:after {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) scale(0);
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-transition: all 450ms cubic-bezier(0.8, 0.5, 0, 1.8);
  transition: all 450ms cubic-bezier(0.8, 0.5, 0, 1.8);
}

.selected .btn:after {
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) scale(1);
  ...
}
```

Comment: did you put prefixes? Show us the css code...

Comment: Do you mean `-webkit-border-radius`? I just tried it but the problem persists.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal I added an overview of the relevant CSS code.